# Cannot reach files found on host with Docker (Failed to open stream: Connection timed out)

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I have the following Docker container setup to power my CMS but I'm having some major issues with a PHP script hosted within the `extensions` volume.

```
version: '2'

services:
    bolt:
        image: rossriley/docker-bolt:3.2
        network_mode: bridge
        environment:
            - BOLT_TITLE=Red Moon Workshop
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - ./db-data:/var/www/html/app/database
            - ./files:/var/www/html/public/files
            - ./app/config:/var/www/html/app/config
            - ./public/theme/redmoon:/var/www/html/public/theme/redmoon
            - ./extensions:/var/www/html/extensions
        restart: always
```

Inside my `extensions` volume I have a PHP script which reads the headers from files stored within the same host. The script is usually a bit more complex but I've boiled it down to one point of failure, this:

```
$image = 'http://beta.redmoonworkshop.us/files/2017-06/1497665310_slide-splash-bg.png';
$headers = get_headers($image);

return $headers;
```

The error complains about it not being able to open the stream due to a timeout, however if I open the URL within the browser it works just fine.

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: get_headers(http://beta.redmoonworkshop.us/files/2017-06/1497665310_slide-splash-bg.png): failed to open stream: Connection timed out")
```

I was able to get this working locally but once I pushed the application to Digital Ocean it's started to fail, so I'm not sure what's happening here. I have a PHP dependency for this script stored inside the Docker container and I have the script stored in a volume, however I've tried it both ways with both on the Docker container with no luck.

If I try and reach any remotely hosted files it works without issue. (Anything from imgur or google etc)

Could this be a permission issue, or some sort of breakdown in communication between Docker and the host? I'm fairly new to both PHP and Docker so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Update #1**

I attempted to cURL the file from the host via the following command and it worked.

```
curl -i http://beta.redmoonworkshop.us/files/2017-06/1497665310_slide-splash-bg.png
```

I attempted to do the same **within** the Docker container and it failed with the following error:

```
Failed to connect to beta.redmoonworkshop.us port 80: Connection timed out
```

If I attempt to Curl the same image (but on localhost) it works.

```
curl -i http://localhost/files/2017-06/1497665310_slide-splash-bg.png
```

Comment: Can you give more context to this: _If I try and reach any remotely hosted files it works without issue._ This sounds like you're accessing a file through the server that is local, getting an error, but if it's a file NOT on the server you're accessing, it works just fine. Is that right?

Comment: Can you post the real URL of the image?  Have you tried using other images off the internet which in the same way.

Comment: @NigelRen Certainly: http://174.138.49.66/files/2017-06/1497665310_slide-splash-bg.png and yes, other images off the internet work just fine. All my script does is looks at the headers, but fails for whatever reason.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Correct.

Comment: Alternative URL for the image if you'd rather a proper url: http://beta.redmoonworkshop.us/files/2017-06/1497665310_slide-splash-bg.png

Comment: Updated the main thread with some results from curling

Comment: It seems like a DNS issue, whereas within your container it's not resolving your site's url correctly or at all. I'm somewhat new to Docker, so unfortunately don't know how to help, but you might try some DNS pokes internally to see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue, I have updated my `docker-compose.yml` file to include an additional set of hosts for the `/etc/hosts` file:

```
extra_hosts:
  - "beta.redmoonworkshop.us:127.0.0.1"
```

Now I'm able to curl the domain and get the files stored on the host machine without issue.